# Facebook comments on my page images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have multiple pictures in my website. I display each image in a thick box with next and back buttons. How I can display comments for each image?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you require? Is it how to get the comments from facebook, or how to display them in the thickbox?

Comment: Both, display and commenting from my site

Comment: Thats a very vague question, StackOverflow is meant for specific questions so if you come back when you have more information we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple [Facebook Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)s on one page. And you can configure plugins with image URLs. So you should put a unique comment plugin for each image.

By this way, you can make all images possible to be commented and you can display different comments for each of them.

Comment: the "Facebook Comments Plugin"

Comment: Please give me an example image URL from your page. I can easily get comment box code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/